# CSS/ html pop up window, what is the best practice?

Tags: html, css

I have a web page and its contents need to be loaded from a pop up window. As an example, when you select options of the pop up window, selected options need to be loaded back to the main page. Can any one suggest me the technique to be used?

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Please take some time to review the [faq]. If you could add some code to show what you've tried so far, it would be helpful for people answering your question. If you invest more time into asking a good question, people will invest more time into writing a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the popup's functions and variables through the window object returned from `open()`.

```
var popup = open("popup.htm");
```

You can access the parent page's functions and variables through the window object returned by `window.opener`.  Once the user selects the options, notify the parent page by calling some function in the parent page:

```
opener.setOptions(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Sorry about that. Hopefully I didn't scare him away.

Comment: Thank you very much, i used this function and able to pass an array to the parent window,so I have my data in a js array, can i use that array values in my php code? i need to print those array values in my page, since im new to this javascript and php this is little difficult for me,thanks for your help

Comment: JavaScript and PHP both are able to print values to the page. If you need those values on the server, it makes sense to to use PHP. Otherwise, you can use JavaScript.  Figure out exactly what you want to do and try it. When you get stuck, post a new, specific question.